# Oracle query getting missing key word exception

Tags: sql, oracle, exception, keyword

```
SELECT *
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN (select * from customers) as t
ON Orders.CustomerID=t.CustomerID;
```

When same query try to execute in mysql it return correct response.
but in the case of oracle its returning missing keyword exception.

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove the `AS` keyword. In Oracle, you only need it for **column alias** and not for **table alias**.
2. Also, the **in-line view** is not required, you could simply use the table_name `customers`.
3. Avoid using `*` in production systems. Use required columns in the SELECT list with proper aliasing if you have similar columns.

```
    SELECT     o.column_list, 
               t.column_list
    FROM       Orders o
    INNER JOIN customers t
    ON         o.CustomerID = t.CustomerID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle SELECT grammar doesn't allow 'AS' keyword before inline view alias, so

```
SELECT * FROM Orders INNER JOIN (select * from customers) t ON Orders.CustomerID=t.CustomerID;
```

And instead of (select * from customers) t you can just use customers t.